# how to get user gender using php sdk v5

Tags: php, facebook

I had made few FB apps on sdk v3.3 and v4.0

but now code seems to be totally changed I've used the following code to get details about the user but it hardly gives id and name not even emailID, gender, firstname and lastname.

```
  $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($accessToken);
  $_SESSION['facebook'] = $accessToken;
  $response = $fb->get('/me');

  $userNode = $response->getGraphUser();
  $id = $userNode->getId();

  print_r($userNode);
```

i've even tried

```
$id = $userNode->getId();
$res = $fb->get('/' . $id);

$user = $res->getGraphUser();
print_r($user);
```

but hard luck the output was the same

> Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [name] => xxxxxxx [id] => 11656415901xxxxx ) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}',
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
  //'default_access_token' => '{access-token}', // optional
]);

try {
  // Get the Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser object for the current user.
  // If you provided a 'default_access_token', the '{access-token}' is optional.
  $response = $fb->get('/me', '{access-token}');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$me = $response->getGraphUser();
echo 'Logged in as ' . $me->getName();
$responseGender = $fb->get('/me?fields=gender', '{access-token}');
print_r($responseGender);
```

Original: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4
There last stable is v5, so I think this is the right way.

Comment: I know this I need to get the user gender which in this case isn't an output of 
 **$me->getGender(); **

Comment: Do request to `$fb->get('/me?fields=gender');`

Comment: You can mace your first request to /me with fileds like `first_name`, `last_name` and `gender`. So you won't make two requests.

Btw, if I helped you, you can vote up ;)

Comment: can I get profile picture like  /photo with php sdk v5?

Comment: Hi @ZeddIndex, you can do it by request to `$fb->get('/me/picture?redirect=false&height=300');`